# how to use $project with condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection as below:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
      {
        "a": 1,
        "bb": 10
      },
      {
        "a": 1,
        "bb": 11
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": [
      {
        "a": 2,
        "bb": 20
      },
      {
        "a": 1,
        "bb": 21
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

in each row of the top collection I have two keys :

> a and b

'b' key is an array of objects with [a, bb] keys.

now, I want to retrieve items of subarray(b) that the key exists in each row.

I want the result to be like this:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "bb": 10
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "bb": 20
  },
]
```

Do you have any idea to solve this?

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8JyQ6Ocx9NH)

Comment: >> now, I want to retrieve items of subarray(b) that the key exists in each row.

What do you mean by this ?? looking at the example do you want to retrieve 0th index `bb` property

Comment: no, in each object id outer 'a' is equal of inner 'a' then return inner object .

Comment: which document's inner object? first or second how you select document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this aggregation
in result you have `a` value and your result as `gg` if you need something else notify me

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    '$project': {
      'a': 1, 
      'gg': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$b', 
          'as': 'z', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$z.a', '$a'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```